# Is there a similar equivalent to get for lists as there is for dicts in python

Tags: python

I'm sure this must have been asked, but I can't seem to find an answer.

Is there a list ~equivalent of get for dictionary. ie to return None if the value is not found at relevant list index.

currently for a list I'm doing

```py
try:
   quote = quotes_results[0]
except IndexError:
   quote = None
```

for a dictionary I could do,
`quote = quotes_results.get('result')`
and it will return None if there is no value at that key.

This is instead of doing

```py
try:
    quote = quotes_results['results']
except KeyError:
    quote = None
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @DirtyBit "Is there a list ~equivalent of get for dictionary"

Comment: @AdamSmith *for a dictionary I could do, quote = quotes_results.get('result') and it will return None if there is no value at that key.*

Comment: @DirtyBit Are you missing the first half of the sentence? OP knows how to do that for a dictionary, and is looking for a similar functionality from a list.

Comment: @DavidCullen great dupe! Thanks!

Comment: @AdamSmith Ah, shoot. I read it the other way around!